# GoogleAuth.signIn().then() not fired

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people) as reference I created this code:

```js
    gapi.load("auth2",function() {
        var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.init({ client_id : "336663289135-huvf4gfmgj7sqf6knb1i13iuam5le8fq.apps.googleusercontent.com"});
        googleAuth.signIn().then(function() {
            // Not fire
            console.log(3);
        });
    });
```

But the function did not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault... I just sign in without user click (for tests) so the browser blocked the popup and not show the regular bar from some reason

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. I am ashamed of how much time I spent before figuring out it was ad-block killing the pop-up. Thank you for the hint!